# How to stop a while loop from executing continuously?

Tags: python, while-loop

Sorry if I phrased the question poorly, I am creating a basic game which generates a random number and asks the user to try guessing the number correctly and helps the user in the process.

```
import random

#print("*************  THE PERFECT GUESS  *****************")

a = random.randint(1,5)

num = int(input("enter a number : "))

while (num<a):
    print("try guessing higher \U0001F615")
    num = int(input("enter a number : "))
    

while (num>a):
    print("try guessing lower  \U0001F615")
    num = int(input("enter a number : "))
    
if (num == a):
    print("yay! You guessed it right,congrats \U0001F60E!")
```

Here , once I execute the program, it gets stuck in the while loop and the compiler asks me to keep guessing forever. Why is the code stuck in the while loop? Its an entry controlled loop so i thought it would break out of the loop as soon as the condition was false.

Comment: Each of your loops exits as soon as its condition is unsatisfied.

Comment: Your while loops should be if statements and your if statement should be your while loop. `while num != a`

Comment: Consider *break*

Answer (score 0):

> Why is the code stuck in the while loop?

Because computers do what tell them to do, not what you want them to do.

```
Num = new_guess()
While num!=a:
  If a<num:
    Too_high()
  Else:
    Too_low()
  Num = new_guess()
```

Sorry for the capitals

Answer (score 0):

For you if you wanted to break put of a loop:
Easiest way:

```
break
```

The harder, force stop way:

```
import sys
sys.exit()
```